# Method that returns the first n odd numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, while-loop

Just a quick question -- I'm probably overlooking something here.

The below method outputs the first 2 odd numbers correctly: [1,3]

If I'm not mistaken, shouldn't I want the length of the array to eventually **equal** n? As I understand it, the length of the outputted array [1,3] is 2, which also represent the first n-many odds: 2.

As such, the comparison in line 6 would now be **<=** rather than **<**

However, if I do that, first_n_odds(2) would now equal [1,3,5], which gives me the first *three* odds. What's going on here?

Thanks!

```
def first_n_odds(n)

   array = []
   current_number = 0

   while array.length < n
      if current_number % 2 == 1
         array << current_number
      end
      current_number += 1 
   end

   return array

end

puts first_n_odds(2)       # output is [1,3]
```

Comment: What makes you think that array length is eventually not `n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do your example with `n == 2`.

Iteration 1: `array.length == 0`.
Iteration 2: `array.length == 1`.

Both of these values are `< 2`. Now if you change `<` to `<=`, you'd have a 3rd iteration where `array.length == 2` since your check happens *before* adding the new element to the array.

Since you seem to be fairly new to Ruby, here are some ways to define the method in a more idiomatic way:

```
# Mapping over a range
def first_n_odds_1(n)
  (0...n).map { |x| x * 2 + 1 }
end

# Mapping over an Enumerator
def first_n_odds_2(n)
  n.times.map { |x| x * 2 + 1}
end

# Using Numeric#step + Enumerable#take
def first_n_odds_3(n)
  1.step(Float::INFINITY, 2).take(n)
end

# A more explicit version of the previous method
def first_n_oods_4(n)
  1.step(by: 2, to: Float::INFINITY).take(n)
end
```

Comment: `(1..n).map { |x| x * 2 + 1 }` misses `1` and includes the (n+1)th odd.

Comment: Oops, yes. As you see I had many different versions and I copied one wrong one from IRB to here. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. Thank you both for guiding me through this! It's been about a month since I'd started learning Ruby, so I really appreciate you guys pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Andy As per StackOverflow etiquette you should eventually accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it:

```
def first_n_odds(n)
  (1..(2*n)).step(2).to_a
end

puts first_n_odds(10).inspect
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Comment: you can write `p first_n_odds(10)` instead of `puts first_n_odds(10).inspect`